# Zuul API Gateway DDOS

Tags: nginx, netflix-zuul, ddos, api-gateway

We are using ZUUL API gateway in our application alongside eureka for service discovery mechanism.

Zuul By itself does not have any mechanism for DDOS and setting up API thresholds AFAIK.

What are my options for prevention of DDOS while using Zuul, shall i have another reverse proxy like nginx before zuul in order to manage things like threshold etc.

Any guidance in this aspect is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use nginx as proxy?

Comment: not currently but the fact remains that nginx also allows me the protection, so can be given a consideration..

Comment: I can give you an answer, but only if you will use nginx as proxy. Or you have to develop DDOS protection from scratch.

Comment: Is it okay? Or you can't use nginx?

Comment: By no means i want to develop a DDOS solution from scratch :)

Comment: Well, I see, I will write some ideas, but not today :)